# android studio simulate hardward key programmatically

Tags: android, button, key

Hi can you help me to simulate key such as home button

i try this but it don't work

```
public void btnClick(View view) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

thans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for home button it works

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
```